# Pandas - Multiplying together pandas dataframe with categoricals

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to implement a method called [mix-up](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.09412). It's where you apply a convex combination to feature of data

```
xk = L*xi+(1-L)*xj

yk = L*yi+(1-L)*yj
```

so for example if I have this fake data:

```
x = [0, 1, 0]
y = [2.0, 3.5, 8]
```

where x `dtype` is `categorical` and y `dtype` is `float`. Then I sample the first 2 rows and apply mix-up. Let's say `L` is 0.5 then. 0(0.5) + 1(0.5)=0.5= new x and new y = 2*(0.5) + 3.5*(0.5) = 2.75 so it would create a new row with x=0.5 an dy=2.75

Where x is features and y is the label in the case of Regression. I converted my categorical features into numeric and now I'm trying to apply mix-up to all features even if they're categorical or not. But I get this error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Categorical' and 'Categorical'`. It is weird to modify a categorical by scaling it and then adding another scaled categorical, but with how this algorithm works that's kind of the only way to do it. How can I force multiply these features?

Comment: Please add real input data, expected output, etc

Comment: It would probably help if you posted the whole function. Are you sure you converted the categorical features to numeric? What dtype is the column, int?

Comment: @rangeseeker it classifies itself as 'categorical', but it's an int. You can click the link under `mix-up` which is a link to the original paper. The equation is just as I described it. I looked into other applications and it seems they either convert it to integer categorical or one-hot encoding. Regardless of which method you end up converting it from categorical to a range.

Comment: Try running df['target column'] = pd.to_numerical(df['source column'])